# Unable to view the marker and animated camera location in map for android app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Hi I am developing a application for school, in that I used navigation drawer to move from one section to another. For all the section I used fragment.

In about_us section I want to display a map and a text view.

1) In which, I can able to view the map and textview but its not showing up the marker in the exact location where I set the lattitude and longitude and also its not showing up the camera update animation. Its simply showing the world map.

2) And if I move from about_us section to another for eg.(Events) then if I again come back to about_us its not opening the page its showing unfortunately the application was closed. (I don't know what happened to my onResume method)

This is the first time I am using Navigation drawer and the Fragment. I don't know why this is happening. This same code is working fine in activity but not in fragment. Kindly help me to fix this.

```
public class AboutUsFragment extends Fragment {

public AboutUsFragment(){}

private GoogleMap gmap;

static final double latitude = 13.12615;
static final double longitude = 80.21932;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);

    initilizeMap();

    return rootView;


}


private void initilizeMap()
{
    if (gmap == null) {
        gmap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (gmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //To enable compass
            gmap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            //To locate the school - Creating Marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Everwin Vidhyashram");

            // adding marker
            gmap.addMarker(marker);

            //We assigned latitude and longitude in Coordinate
            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            CameraUpdate schoolLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 5);
            gmap.animateCamera(schoolLocation);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(coordinate)         // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
            .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //initilizeMap();

    if (gmap == null) {
        gmap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (gmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Generate signed apk using export tool first & then install it on your devices, You will get marker on map

Comment: I fixed the marker issue by adding all my coding in the onActivityCreated() method. Only onResume() is not working now. Can you tell me how to fix this issue. The app is getting closed when I resume the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your code from  if (gmap == null) {}. This is what happens if map is not created.

```
private void initilizeMap()
{
    if (gmap == null) {
        gmap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (gmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

//To enable compass
            gmap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            //To locate the school - Creating Marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Everwin Vidhyashram");

            // adding marker
            gmap.addMarker(marker);

            //We assigned latitude and longitude in Coordinate
            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            CameraUpdate schoolLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 5);
            gmap.animateCamera(schoolLocation);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(coordinate)         // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
            .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon, Didn't get what you are saying. Do I need to remove if(gmap == null) { .... } completely???

Comment: no , see what i did . Remove MarkerOptions and CameraPosition from this if(gmap == null). This if (gmap == nul) check is map create or isn't. Your map is created and your code are does not execute.

Comment: Bro, Now I fixed the camera update and marker, but not on resume. What I did is. 

I added onActivityCreated after onCreateView method and added all the marker and camera coding. Then I added a initializeMap(){..} method below on onActivityCreated method and inserted the if(map == null){...} coding alone in that. After that I added on resume method. Now everything is working fine. Except onResume method.

@Override
 public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  initilizeMap();
 }

If I navigate from about_us to another and come back again to this. its unfortunately getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

In your create activity call getMap method like this.

```
public class ShowMap extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_location_map);

  getMap();
 }
```

}

```
public void getMap(){




      int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);


            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
           googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        }





}
```

use this in to your onLocationChanged method of map .

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location ) {


 // Getting latitude of the current location
 double latitude = location.getLatitude();

 // Getting longitude of the current location
 double longitude = location.getLongitude();

 // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

 // Showing the current location in Google Map
 googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

 // Zoom in the Google Map
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

}
```

Comment: this is for getting current location on the map

Comment: Now marker and the camera update is working fine. Only onResume method is not working properly. When ever the fragment get resume. Its showing unfortunately the application was closed.